# Conditionally renaming sub variables after exploding a main associative array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The code below works fine, but after running list() on the exploded sub variables ($disc1, $disc2, $disc3) I need to conditionally rename the data that's inside them.

Basically, the field 'discs' is stored in our db as a composite of acronyms (i.e., a user's CD choices are CD-DA-RD), I can separate them out but not rename. I need something like:

'CB' -> 'CLUB'

'DA' -> 'DANCE'

'RD' -> 'RADIO'

I assume I need to get $disc1, $disc2, $disc3 back into an array to do this?

Hope someone can help - thanks!

```
// create a function to produce the main associative array from mySQL field 'discs'

function get_user_discs($myusername) {
   $discs  = array();
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT `discs`                 
                         FROM `members` 
                         WHERE `email` = '{$myusername}'");
   if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
     $disc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
   }

   return $discs;
}

// call the function

$temp = $_SESSION['myusername'];
$discs = get_user_discs($temp);

 // explode $discs into individual parts using delimiter

list($disc1, $disc2, $disc3) = explode("-", $discs['discs'], 3);

// then rename($disc1, $disc2, $disc3) to full names....?
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What do you want to "rename" `$disc1` to?

Comment: Do you have (or could you create) a table where the associations of 'CB' -> 'CLUB','DA' -> 'DANCE', 'RD' -> 'RADIO' are stored? If so, you could join the tables in the select and then create an associative array with the returned data e.g. `'CD'=>'Club'`

Comment: Rocket Hazmat - I need to *conditionally* rename the values that are stored in $disc1, $disc2, $disc3. The values that are currently stored are 'CB', 'DA' or 'RD'. What I need is their full version - 'CLUB', 'DANCE', 'RADIO'

Comment: mseifert - thanks for the response - that could work, I will try!